# Compare two colonne for some table with eloquent laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to compare **two column**  for the same table Using Eloquent ORM in Laravel.

```
Cadeau::where('user_theme_id','=',$liste_id)->where('current_user_id', '=', 'user_id');
```

current_user_id and user_id are the tow column of cadeau table

Answer (score 9):

Use `WhereRaw` to execute a raw where query

```php
Cadeau::where('user_theme_id','=',$liste_id)
       ->whereRaw('current_user_id = user_id')->get();
```