# Laravel Eloquent Compare Column Values

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Eloquent's `where()` seems not working when comparing two column values. How to fix it?

Sample code:

```
->where('table_1.name', '=', 'table_2.name')
```

But works on:

```
->where('table_1.name', '=', 'john')
```

Comment: you can accept my answer for further readers if it was helpful :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two colonne for some table with eloquent laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311540/compare-two-colonne-for-some-table-with-eloquent-laravel)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Escaping is unnecessary in this case, you can use `whereRaw()`:

```
->whereRaw('table_1.name = table_2.name')
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks! I also answered my question in addition to your solution. I'll vote up your answer when my vote credits regenerates.

Comment: is there any way to do this using "where " Clause

Answer (score 78):

You can use where column:

```
->whereColumn('table_1.name', 'table_2.name')
```

Comment: Just want to add that this method is only added in laravel 5. Use method in other answer if you are working on laravel 4 project like me.

Comment: You can also pass a comparison operator and/or an array of multiple conditions. eg, ->whereColumn([
                    ['first_name', '=', 'last_name'],
                    ['updated_at', '>', 'created_at']
]);

Answer (score 16):

I figured it out. `'table_2.name'` is interpreted as plain string and not a mysql table column.

Possible solutions:

1. Wrap `'table_2.name'`with `\DB::raw()`

   ```
   ->where('table_1.name', '=', \DB::raw('table_2.name'))
   ```
2. Wrap the entire expression with `whereRaw()` (based on @limonte's answer)

   ```
   ->whereRaw('table_1.name = table_2.name')
   ```

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I just added an alternative solution. Not necessarily a better solution :)