# Using two columns in where Laravel ORM

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent, laravel-5

I have two columns in my table: `max` and `current`. I want to build simple scope

```
public function scopeNotMax($query)
{
    return $query->where('max', '>', 'current');
}
```

But Laravel gives me that query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `max` > 'current'
```

I don't want this result and I know that I can use in this place `whereRaw()` or `DB::raw()`. But I can't find another way to say "hey, this is column, not string!'. Can I do it? Or I must use raws? I want to avoid it.

Comment: Even in the Laravel's doc it used `whereRaw` when it needed this https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#advanced-where-clauses  look at the Exists Statements section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no other way.

`where()` method in this case add third parameter (value) to bindings and passes it ot PDO library. So it will be escaped.

Alternatively You can pass as third parameter a Closure, but then laravel will form a sub-select for You, which doesn't helps much.

Looks like `whereRaw()` is made for this kind of sitiuation.

Comment: `whereRaw()` sucks because not formatting columns :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you give a try with this ? `return $query->where('max > current');`

Comment: I found this one for you! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331437/laravel-eloquent-compare-column-values

Comment: The answer can become more valuable if you added some explanation and links to documentation, so the original poster and other users can actually learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use whereRaw():

```
->whereRaw('table_1.name = table_2.name');
```

You exmaple code:

```
->whereRaw('max>current');
```