# mysql select * from table where column a value = column b value laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, laravel

Im trying to query a table with column called completed and column called follow_ups among other columns - using laravel im trying to

```
 select * from table where completed > follow_ups 
 select * from table where completed = follow_ups
```

using laravel model im running the following

```
 $followUps = TestFollowups::where('follow_ups', '>', 'completed')->get();
```

I dont have to use laravels model system i can write a manual query as well but unsure what the query should look like. Can anyone help please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331437/laravel-eloquent-compare-column-values

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what i needed

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
whereRaw(select * from table where completed > follow_ups)
```