# Laravel ORM is giving an incorrect result on a simple query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I really don't get it, help me understand.

I'm writing an app which among other things calculates a NFL team "mark" (a mark is Win/Lose/Tie, sorry I don't know the word in English for that), so I have a "Marca" attribute in the Team model, looks like this:

```
public function getMarcaAttribute() {
    ...
}
```

Queries are very easy, first I get the number of games where the team is playing as local and calculate wins, loses and ties, for example, this one is for wins:

```
$gan += Juego::where('local', $this->id)
                  ->where('score_local', '>', 'score_visitante')
                  ->get()->count();
```

Then I do the same with games as visitor, but inverting comparison signs, of course.

Now, lets take a look at game Seattle (38) at Atlanta (25), if I do in the database

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM juegos WHERE local='atl' AND score_local > score_visitante;
```

Of course, it returns 0.

In the ORM, the generated query is:

```
  array (
    'query' => 'select * from `juegos` where `local` = ? and `score_local` > ? and `score_local` is not null',
    'bindings' => 
    array (
      0 => 'atl',
      1 => 'score_visitante',
    ),
    'time' => 0.89,
  ),
```

The thing is returning a 1. I even replaced the `->count()->get()` for a `->get()` and do a `foreach` over the results:

```
$gan = Juego::where('local', $this->id)
              ->where('score_local', '>', 'score_visitante')
              ->get();

Log::info('Ganados');
foreach ($gan as $g) {
  Log::info("$g->score_local > $g->score_visitante");
}
```

The thing is returning a line where it says "25 > 38"

I really don't understand what happens here. Any idea?

Comment: because `where` is taking a "value" and comparing it to the column not comparing 2 columns  ... perhaps you want `whereColumn`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Eloquent Compare Column Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331437/laravel-eloquent-compare-column-values)

Comment: What???? so it is comparing against 'score_visitante' as a string and not as a column???? This is frustrating. I thought I was following documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#advanced-wheres

Comment: you are using laravel 5.0? that is severely out of data

Comment: I'm using 7.1.3

Comment: so then why would you be using the documentation for Laravel 5.0 ?  you are just frustrating yourself

Comment: Because I went to Google... tell me where is that in 7. It hasn't changed that much in the ORM. I was doing this from my memory... `where(column, comparisor, compare_to_what)`. Thank you a lot anyway, I just learned not only how (whereRaw) but also why (your answer)

Comment: go to the version 7.x of the docs (the upper right is the version drop down) and then type `whereColumn` into the search bar and you will get to the section and then you can scroll through it and you will find it

Comment: Now that I review what you say and what I got in the logs makes perfectly sense, in the bindings it is goingo for a value, not a column. Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/debugging-queries-in-laravel looks helpful

Comment: Thanks! there's a chrome extension (I don't recall the name, I have it in my office PC) that allows you to do some debugging in the laravel, including the "calls" to the database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using `whereRaw` :

```php
$gan = Juego::where('local', $this->id)
              ->whereRaw('score_local > score_visitante')
              ->get();
```

Or as suggested in comments, `whereColumn`:

```php
$gan = Juego::where('local', $this->id)
              ->whereColumn('score_local', '>' , 'score_visitante')
              ->get();
```

Comment: Yes it does, `->whereRaw()` works as I wanted. I don't know why the heck is `->where()` for, `->whereRaw()` is more compact and more readable. Thanks a lot. I've been cursing all morning long!!!

Comment: @luisfer In most cases when you're using `where()`, you're supplying a value to check the database against, not specifying another column... The syntax is roughly equivalent `where($column, $operator, $value)`, not `where($column, $operator, $anotherColumn)`. That's why the `whereRaw()` or `whereColumn()` methods exist. Don't rely on `whereRaw()` too much, as Laravel is supposed to be language-agnostic, meaning that it will work for all DB languages (MySQL, Postgres, etc), but `whereRaw()` doesn't work that way. That all being said, this answer handles your case perfectly :)

Comment: Tim is right. I would add that if at any point you want to use dynamic values in `whereRaw` queries be very careful to use the correct bindings to avoid sql injections: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#raw-methods

Comment: Right... I knew that `whereRaw()` existed but I wanted to be, as you say, agnostic. I mostly work with mySQL for my own things, at work we use much more Postgres. In this case, I'll keep the `whereRaw()` since its for me... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@lagbox had it figured out in the comments. The problem is that by using prepared statements with bindings the term `score_visitante` is not been treated as a column name rather than a string.

There are several ways to solve it:

1. Use Eloquent method `whereColumn`:

```php
$gan += Juego::where('local', $this->id)
                  ->whereColumn('score_local', '>', 'score_visitante')
                  ->count();
```

2. Use Eloquent method `whereRaw`:

```php
$gan += Juego::where('local', $this->id)
                  ->whereRaw('score_local > score_visitante')
                  ->count();
```

3. Use `DB::raw`:

```php
$gan += Juego::where('local', $this->id)
                  ->where('score_local', '>', \DB::raw('score_visitante'))
                  ->count();
```

---

> Note: You also do not need the `->get()` before the `->count()`. You can instruct the database to do the counting. This is particularly useful when the expected result is a large dataset with many rows, by returning just a number instead of potentially thousands or even millions of rows you are preserving your network resources.

Comment: Yeah... I'll have to check a lot of queries where I have tried to compare columns... maybe they were working by mere luck.

Comment: BTW, the `->whereNotNull()` is unnecesary, it was part of my frustration, I thought it may be counting NULL values (which of course would make no sense), I'll edit the question

Comment: OK thanks, that's new... so I end the sentence with just `->count()`? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @luisfer Calling `->get()` on a Query (a `Builder` instance) returns a Collection, which has a `count()` method. Conveniently, the `Builder` class also has a `count()` method, so you can call `->count()` directly and bypass the need for a Collection.